# Terraform with Azure Key Vault to get secret value

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

Is there any way to get the value of a secret from Azure Key Vault?

Doesn't look like `value` gets exposed in the key vault secret object [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/key_vault_secret.html).

Comment: When reporting some issues and asking for help, you need to provide details, such as error, codes you used with `azurerm_key_vault_secret`, and so on.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Now you can do it with [azurerm_key_vault_secret](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_secret) data source.

I'm enjoying without any scripting.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "some-resource-group"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
  name      = "secret-sauce"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  # vault_uri is deprecated in latest azurerm, use key_vault_id instead.
  # vault_uri = "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/"
}

output "secret_value" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value}"
}
```

Comment: looks like vault_uri is deprecated and removed now

Comment: Insted of value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value}" you can directly provide value = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value

Answer (score 13):

You first need to create a data resource to the azure key vault to get the key vault resource ID:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "${var.keyvault_name}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.resourcegroup_name}"
}
```

And then use `azurerm_key_vault_secret` to get the secret with the key vault resource Id:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "win_admin_pass" {
  name         = "${var.secret_name}"
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id}"
}
```

Please note that the use of `vault_uri` in `azurerm_key_vault_secret` is deprecated and not recommended.

Comment: Note that you can (now) also use `var.secret_name` instead of `"${var.secret_name}"`.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on this to get password from key vault secret. The code below worked for me , Give it a try.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "terrakv" {
  name                = "terrakv" // KeyVault name
  resource_group_name = "mykv" // resourceGroup
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvsecret" {
name = "secret" // Name of secret
key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.terrakv.id
}

os_profile {
computer_name  = "vm-01"
admin_username = "testadmin"
admin_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kvsecret.value // Toget actual value
}
```

I hope it will help you for sure.

Comment: giving Cyclic dependency error

Answer (score 3):

I have a key vault and I need a few secrets from it so this is my approach.
I've used **for-each** approach

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault_devops" {
 name                = "keyVaultName"
 resource_group_name = "resourceGroupName"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secrets" "global_devops" {
 key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault_devops.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "global_devops" {
 for_each     = toset(data.azurerm_key_vault_secrets.global_devops.names)
 name         = each.key
 key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.global_devops.id
}
```

Then I use it like this :

**value           = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.global_devops["secret-name"].value**

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the value of a secret from Azure Key Vault?

As a workaround, we can use `PowerShell` to get this value, like this:

```
$a = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "jasonkey" -Name "jason"
$a.SecretValueText
```

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Does this work for you? Please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it wasn't helpful, as I was looking for a solution using Terraform, not Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible in Terraform. Terraform will only output the secret ID and version. If you need to retrieve azure keyvault secrets, the best method is to use the Azure-CLI, or Powershell if that's not available.

**Using Azure-CLI (2.0)**

```
az keyvault secret show --vault-name <vault-name> --name <secret-name>
```

Syntax:

```
az keyvault secret show --name
                        --vault-name
                        [--version]
```

For more, see: [Managing Azure Keyvault Secrets with Azure-CLi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest)

---

**Using Powershell**: [Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret?view=azurermps-5.5.0)

```
get-azurekeyvaultsecret -vaultName "<vault-name>" -name "<secret-name>"
```

Comment: thanks! I know how to do it with Azure CLI, was looking for solution in Terraform.

Comment: even with Hashicorp Vault, they don't support a data source to retrieve secrets. The reason is that it would be exposed or available through state, which negates security of having the vault in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I was curious because with Azure Resource Manager it is possible to get the value of the Azure Key Vault secret

Comment: Yes, as any API would. Also is the case for hashicorp vault. Terraform can't solve this problem until they support the ability to retrieve Secrets without storing the values in state